# Android and IOUtils.toByteArray

Tags: android, http

I write app on android which will send xml file to PHP server. Here is my code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postReq = new HttpPost("http://majkelsoftgames.cba.pl/ser/server.php");

byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
InputStreamBody isb= new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), "file");

MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
multipartContent.addPart("file", isb);

postReq.setEntity(multipartContent);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postReq);
```

My problem is that when

```
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

is executing I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
```

I downloaded external commons-io.jar from http://commons.apache.org/io/ and added this jar to the java build path in android project. I really have no idea what I am doing wrong. Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added it to the build path, but did you place it in the /libs directory of youur project?  That is the only way it will get added to your apk.

Comment: That's not quite true. You can add it to your build path and **export** it, and it will be added to your apk as well.